# Brake Caliper play

Tags: brakes

2011 Nissan XTrail T31 Diesel, 110kw. Service guy changed the brake pads yesterday and now there's a vibration when braking slowly at low speeds. Brakes hold fine in other situations.

I've driven the car for about 600km before, with the old pads and the issue was not present.

Noticed that there is caliper play on front right wheel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhydz.jpg

Took it back to the service, guy rechecked all bolts, says everything's tight.

He said to come back later, for an more in-detail checkup.

What coukd it be?

Thanks

Comment: Were the rotors replaced or resurfaced? It is best to put new pads on a clean flat disc surface to avoid strange behavior.

Comment: @vini_i same old rotors. Just changed the pads. Issue was not present with worn pads.

Comment: Old rotors (without resurfacing) are never perfectly flat. The surface where the pad contacts the rotor does not wear evenly. The old pads wear along with the rotor and conform to this unevenness. New pads are flat and now make odd contact with the uneven rotor.

Answer (score 1):

The calliper pins should be greased with brake grease after each change. I've forgotten to do that once on an older car and had some issues. It could be the pins aren't sliding smoothly at low speeds?

The rotors should either be changed or resurfaced each time as well. The old pads wear the rotors oddly sometimes, so the new ones don't make perfect contact, leading to issues. You 'can' sort of get away with this if the brake rotors show very little wear. (As per vini_i's note in the comments too).

The brake shims should have been changed too, if you can see them they should be shiny and new. Just allows for the pads to move as freely as they should.

I think generally, you're going to have some play in the calliper, it shouldn't be excessive. But if you look at a diagram of the brakes the callipers are almost floating on the pins.

If you quickly touch the hub / calliper area after a drive and it's super hot, or start to see 'blueing' on the rotors. (or smell a burning smell from the brake area) I wouldn't drive the car except to a shop to get it dealt with. Or do it yourself. Changing brake pads and rotors can be a pretty easy job with a manual and/or youtube. If you have some basic tools. Then at least you know what was done, or not done.