# Shock absorber anti sway bar support

Tags: nissan, diesel, shock-absorber, x-trail

2011 Nissan Xtrail T31 Diesel.

The support that holds the sway bar link looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVk7i.jpg.

Can this be welded? Or should I buy a new set of shock absorbers?

How dangerous is to drive 500km more like this?

Thanks

Comment: Could be the cause of this question : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/66733/10976 and how come the mech you took it to did not spot it/

Comment: @SolarMike There were no braking issues with the old pads. We did notice it when I went to replace the pads

Comment: Can you add a photo of the other shock absorber for comparison?

Comment: @HandyHowie Here it is https://imgur.com/vScyW11

Comment: If it was my car, I would TIG weld it up. It doesn't look like it needs an emergency fix, but I would do it as soon as possible.  That is only my opinion based on what I can see.  There could be a crack developing underneath that nut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, not only can you drive 500 miles, but you can drive it until the car falls apart.

Second. From the look of it that is a cut. Not a crack. It looks like it has been there for a long time. Taking into account the rust that has developed. That sway bar link connection is not going to change.

You can technically disconnect or remove the sway bar links. Your car will drive almost the same as least as far a normal driver can tell. With the exception that you may notice it being less stable when you make sharp turns.

If you want pice of mind have your mechanic weld it where the cut is located. I bet he will not want to do that or recommend it since it won't bring much money.

Comment: Yeah, upon further inspection, those were small cuts, from previous work. They cut the nut off, and touched the sway bar support with the angle grinder...

Answer (score 0):

If it was my car, I would TIG weld it up. It doesn't look like it needs an emergency fix, but I would do it as soon as possible. That is only my opinion based on what I can see. There could be a crack developing underneath that nut.